# Spark timeout on writing to parquet

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

I get a timeout on running this notebook in databricks. The last step in writing to parquet is taking approx 15-18 mins before timeout error occurs. I'm not sure as to where it goes wrong.

```
from pyspark.sql.functions import explode, sequence

# Create hours string
spark.sql(f"select explode(array('00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23')) as hh").createOrReplaceTempView('hours')

# Create minutes string
spark.sql(f"select explode(array('00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59')) as mm").createOrReplaceTempView('minutes')

# Create seconds string
spark.sql(f"select explode(array('00', '01', '02', '03', '04', '05', '06', '07', '08', '09', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59')) as ss").createOrReplaceTempView('seconds')

# Create Time string, add hour, minute, second
spark.sql(f"select CAST(CONCAT(hours.hh, ':', minutes.mm, ':', seconds.ss) as string) as Time, explode(sequence(0,23,1)) as Hour from hours cross join minutes cross join seconds ").createOrReplaceTempView('time1')
spark.sql(f"select *, explode(sequence(0,59,1)) as Minute from time1").createOrReplaceTempView('time2')
spark.sql(f"select *, explode(sequence(0,59,1)) as Second from time2").createOrReplaceTempView('time3')

# Add TimeID
spark.sql(f"select row_number() over (order by TIME) as TimeID, * from time3").createOrReplaceTempView('src')

# Add HourDescription
spark.sql(f"select *, CONCAT(CASE date_part('HOUR', Time) WHEN 0 THEN '00' WHEN 1 THEN '01' WHEN 2 THEN '02' WHEN 3 THEN '03' WHEN 4 THEN '04' WHEN 5 THEN '05' WHEN 6 THEN '06' WHEN 7 THEN '07' WHEN 8 THEN '08' WHEN 9 THEN '09' END, ':00') as HourDescription from src").createOrReplaceTempView('src1')

# Add HourBucket
spark.sql(f"select *, CONCAT(HourDescription, ' - ', CONCAT(CASE date_part('HOUR', Time) WHEN 0 THEN '01' WHEN 1 THEN '02' WHEN 2 THEN '03' WHEN 3 THEN '04' WHEN 4 THEN '05' WHEN 5 THEN '06' WHEN 6 THEN '07' WHEN 7 THEN '08' WHEN 8 THEN '09' WHEN 9 THEN '10' WHEN 10 THEN '11' WHEN 11 THEN '12' WHEN 12 THEN '13' WHEN 13 THEN '14' WHEN 14 THEN '15' WHEN 15 THEN '16' WHEN 16 THEN '17' WHEN 17 THEN '18' WHEN 18 THEN '19' WHEN 19 THEN '20' WHEN 20 THEN '21' WHEN 21 THEN '22' WHEN 22 THEN '23' WHEN 23 THEN '00' END, ':00')) as HourBucket from src1").createOrReplaceTempView('src2')

# Add DayPart
spark.sql(f"select *, CASE WHEN (Hour >= 0  AND Hour < 6) THEN 'Night' WHEN (Hour >= 6  AND Hour < 12) THEN 'Morning' WHEN (Hour >= 12  AND Hour < 18) THEN 'Afternoon' ELSE 'Evening' END as DayPart FROM src2").createOrReplaceTempView('src3')

# Add BusinessHour
spark.sql(f"select *, CASE WHEN (Hour >= 8  AND Hour < 18) THEN 'Yes' ELSE 'No' END as BusinessHour FROM src3").createOrReplaceTempView('src_final')

#Write to Parquet
df = sqlContext.sql("select * from src_final");
df.write.parquet("/mnt/xxx/xx/xxx/")
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. the explode(sequence) took alot of effort. Especially as soon as the one for minutes stepped in. I fixed the code like this:

```
# Create Time string, add hour, minute, second
spark.sql(f"select CAST(CONCAT(hours.hh, ':', minutes.mm, ':', seconds.ss) as string) as Time, cast(hours.hh as int) as Hour, cast(minutes.mm as int) as Minute, cast(seconds.ss as int) as Second from hours cross join minutes cross join seconds ").createOrReplaceTempView('time')
```